# 2 routers in the same network - signal issues

Tags: wireless-networking, signal, windows-phone

I've got a weird issue in my brand new house. Asked few smarter than me people, so far without success.

BACKGROUND:
My house has got 2 levels (ground and first floor). Internet cable from the very beginning was only on the ground floor. So this is the place in which I've got main router/modem (TPLINK TD-W8960N). Because of house construction there was no WIFI available on the first floor. Because I didn't want to drill anywhere I've decided to use powerline adapters (tplink TL-PA2010KIT). After connecting that set with additional router on the 1st floor (TPLINK w8961NB) i was able to propegate wifi signal on that area. Half of the success.

ISSUE:
While going from the ground to the 1st floor / opposite way, all devices use as primary, first used router. So e.g. when I connect my laptop to the 'ground' router, after going upstairs still tries to used it. I need to disable/enable wifi to connect to the strongest wifi signal. Same story with opposite way (connecting for the first time router on 1st floor, and then going down).

In the 1st floor router, I've changed the following settings:
- router IP changed from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.2
- I've disabled DHCP
- set SSID/Passes for wifi same as in the ground router

What else I can do to solve this issue? I dont want off/on the wifi in my laptop/tablet/phone just to get strongest signal..

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is set the "roaming aggressiveness" of you wifi adapter. You should be able to do this by

1. going to network and sharing center (right click the wifi icon)
2. select change adapter settings
3. select your wifi adapter and select properties
4. click the "configure" button on the popup window (network tab)
5. click the advanced tab
6. if roaming aggressiveness is there, set it to "highest.
   Your laptop should now seek out the strongest signal.

If roaming aggressiveness isn't there then play around with 'Roam Tenancy' and 'Roaming Decision'.

I don't think this is possible for mobile phones.